# Angular 15+ No provider for TemplateRef when structural directive used as hostDirective

Tags: angular, angular15

There is a possibility to bind standalone directives to component and directive decorator since angular version 15. Is there a way how to use structural directive (injecting templateRef) as hostDirective? It would be super usefull, but as I try anyhow I always get No provider for TemplateRef.

[stackblitz to play](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-host-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirective.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

In your provided demo, you are using a `standalone` directive into a no-standalone component, in this case `HelloComponent` is contained in `AppModule`, so in order to use your `directive`, you would need to import into the `imports` array, like if it were a `module`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MyIfDirective], // directive here
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If `HelloComponent` were `standalone`, then you would require to import it into the component's metadata `imports` array.

Comment: I've made HelloComponent standalone and it does not help... Could you please provide some working example? I've also tried to add @Injectable decorator to directive, but nothing helps. I would say it is not possible to use structural directives in hostDirectives

Comment: I am sorry, but your directive is not even applied in this case. Therefor it can't be used to hide/show content based on some input. Content will be shown all the time. My example is just a proof of failure :) but I would like to use structural directives as hostDirectives exactly and this is simulating it

Answer (score -1):

```
you need make changes in directive.ts, don't declare TemplateRef in constructor rather declare it in directive class:
import {
  Directive,
  Injectable,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
@Directive({
  selector: '[myIf]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class MyIfDirective {
  tpl: TemplateRef<any>
  constructor( private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
}
you can refer to this stackblitz link, I have made changes in directive.ts: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-host-directive-uw5wkq
```

Comment: your directive is nor working at all. as you won't inject TemplateRef, the content is still present in DOM. this.tpl is undefined in your ngOnInit

Comment: Please check the stackblitz link that I have provided, working fine in it.

Comment: take a look into browser's console. there is an error ;)